# Find the shortest distance in hashmap

Tags: algorithm, sorting, hashmap, distance, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to resolve an algorithm from google example interview.

We have 5 blocks. Every block can have gym, store or shop, or have 2 of them or all.
And we have to find the block which have the smallest distance to all objects. (it can be in pseudo code or any language)

```
        val blocks1 = hashMapOf(
            "gym" to false,
            "school" to true,
            "store" to false,
        )
        val blocks2 = hashMapOf(
            "gym" to true,
            "school" to false,
            "store" to false,
        )
        val blocks3 = hashMapOf(
            "gym" to true,
            "school" to true,
            "store" to false,
        )
        val blocks4 = hashMapOf(
            "gym" to false,
            "school" to true,
            "store" to false,
        )
        val blocks5 = hashMapOf(
            "gym" to false,
            "school" to true,
            "store" to true,
        )
```

The answer is block 4, because we have 1 step to gym and 1 step to store and 0 step to school

[Whole example interview, it is 1st question from this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rw4s4M3hFfs&t=2088s&ab_channel=Cl%C3%A9mentMihailescu)

In my opinion what are they doing on this video is without sense, but I don't have my own plan for resolve it.

Could someone give me some tips how to resolve it ?
What steps I should do ?
Maybe I should use a special algorithm for that which already exist ?

Answer (score 2):

Considering the given example, we need to compute a `5*5` matrix, say `A` of block distance values, where `A[i][j]` is the distance between `i` and `j`.
This distance is 0 if either of the two conditions meets:

- Both blocks don't have the amenities (in which case distance is pointless)
- Both blocks have the amenities (in this case it is clearly 0, since no need to travel)

Else,
distance = distance between `i` and `j` = `abs(i-j)`

Important to note here is that this matrix is symmetric, so you can simply loop over the lower half of the matrix only, so essentially, instead of looping through `5*5 = 25`, you would be computing distance through `5*(5-1)/2 = 10` iterations only.

Following code in Python does just that -

```
import sys

blocks = [{'gym': False, 'school': True, 'store': False},
          {'gym': True, 'school': False, 'store': False},
          {'gym': True, 'school': True, 'store': False},
          {'gym': False, 'school': True, 'store': False},
          {'gym': False, 'school': True, 'store': True}]

reqs = ['gym', 'school', 'store']

q = len(blocks)

min_dist = sys.maxsize
block_idx = -1

for col in range(q-1):
    for row in range(col+1, q):
        row_b = blocks[row]
        col_b = blocks[col]

        dist = 0
        for req in reqs:
            if row_b[req] == col_b[req]:
                dist += 0
            else:
                dist += abs(row-col)

        if dist < min_dist:
            min_dist = dist
            block_idx = row

        print(f"({row}, {col}):\t{dist}")

print(f"Output block index: {block_idx}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FUNCTION Has( B, A )    // true if block B has amenity A
   IF B does not exist
       RETURN FALSE
   IF B has A
       RETURN TRUE
   RETURN FALSE

FUNCTION Distance( B, A )   // Distance from block B to nearest amenity A
   FOR D = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
   IF Has( B+D, A )
      RETURN D
   IF Has( B-D, A )
      RETURN D
   IF D > number of blocks
      OUTPUT Amenity A is nowhere to be found
      STOP

BESTB = -1           // block with best score so far
BESTSCORE = -1       // best score so far
LOOP B over blocks
   S = 0             // score for block B
   LOOP A over gym, school, store
       S = S + Distance( B, A )
   IF S == 0
      OUTPUT B
      STOP
   IF S < BESTSCORE
      BESTB = B
      BESTSCORE = S
OUTPUT BESTB
STOP
```

Comment: What is Bestb ? Could you write something like comments ? My brain can't handle it, I was trying to resolve it for all week

Comment: BESTB is the block with the best score so far

Answer (score 1):

Scan the distance from front and back. When doing front add 1 to previous distance or set distance to zero if building present. When doing back set distance to zero if  building present else set distance to previous plus one.

The one with the least distance wins.

Totally untested code

```
enum building { gym, school, store, Last };
std::vector<std::array<int, Last>> dist;
dist.resize(blocks.size()+1);
dist[0] = { MAXINT, MAXINT, MAXINT> };
// forward scan
unsigned block = 0;
for (auto & build : blocks) {
  for (auto idx = gym; gym != Last; idx++) {
     if (build[idx])
       dist[block][idx]= 0;
     if (dist[block][idx] != MAXINT)
       dist[block+1][idx] = dist[block][idx]+1;
  }
}

// backward scan
block = blocks.size()-1;
int bestblock = 0;
int bestsum = MAXINT;
for (auto it = blocks.rbegin(); it != std::next(blocks.rend()): it++) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (auto idx = gym; gym != Last; idx++) {
     auto build = it[idx];
     if (build)
       dist[block][idx] = 0;
     else
       dist[block][idx] = std::min(dist[block+1][idx]+1, dist[block][building]);
     sum += dist[block][idx];
  }
  if (sum < bestsum) {
    bestsum = sum;
    bestblock = block;
  }
  block--;
}

std::cout << "Best block = " << bestblock << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

The objective is to reduce the complexity from N*N to N. Hope below table helps to clarify the algo.

[image]